# StatusBar is getting lost

Tags: c#, wpf

I set up my statusBar this way:

```
<tx:StatusBar
    x:Name="ssbEdicao"
    Grid.Row="0"  
    IsVisibleChanged="ssbEdicao_IsVisibleChanged"
    IsEnabled="True"
    Grid.Column="0"
    PageText="Página: "
    PageCounterText="/"
    SectionText="Seção: "
    SectionCounterText="/"
    LineText="Linha: "
    ColumnText="Coluna: "
    ShowZoom="True"
    Focusable="True"
    Visibility="Visible"
    BorderStyle="VerticalColorScheme" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <tx:StatusBar.DisplayColors>
        <tx:StatusBarColors
            BackColor="#FFDCE7F5"
            FrameColor="Silver"
            BackColorBottom="#FFDCE7F5"
            BackColorMiddle="#FFF7F7F7" />
    </tx:StatusBar.DisplayColors>
</tx:StatusBar>
```

But when I open a print window, and go back to the previous window that only set the `IsVisible = false` property, it no longer takes the cursor, such as row and column, or properties like Zoom and CapsLock.

Comment: Any relevant C# code that involves your question?

Comment: does not have any code that is relevant.

Comment: @Verin no relevant code? Ok, then a different question: what is the namespace behind `tx`? It seems you are using something different (unknown to us) instead of the WPF standard `StatusBar`.

Comment: Tx would be the controls of the tool that I use as support